# Android Studio does not show all build variants

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-productflavors

Below are the `buildTypes` and `flavors` parts of my build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
    }
}

flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    free {
        android.sourceSets.free.setRoot('src/main')
        dimension "default"
    }
    plus {
        applicationIdSuffix '.plus'
        versionName '1.0'
        android.sourceSets.plus.setRoot('src/plus')
        dimension "default"
    }
}
```

Android Studio only shows two build variants (`freeDebug` and `freeRelease`) in the Build variants window. It does not show `plusDebug` or `plusRelease`. I have another project with a similar build.gradle and I can clearly see four build variants. Any ideas where I should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plus` is a default method in groovy. It's not a bug in Android Studio or anything else. You are executing this function in `DefaultGroovyMethods`

```
public static <T> Set<T> plus(Set<T> left, T right) {
    return (Set)plus((Collection)left, (Object)right);
}
```

This is because the delegate passed into `productFlavors` implements `Set`.

See [productFlavors definition](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension:productFlavors(org.gradle.api.Action))

Comment: When I tried quoting it -- `"plus"` -- I had the same result as `plus`. Does Groovy treat string literals as method names?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug/limitation in Gradle. I have filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73832078) for it.

Use something else, other than `plus`. I tried quoting it (`"plus"`), thinking that perhaps it's a conflict with a keyword, but that had no effect. But `Plus` and `plussss` and `phat` all work.

Comment: Thank you! Your original comment actually helped and it was correct (not using 'plus') but for the wrong reason.

Comment: They should at least put a warning about the "plus" word. It's a very common word to use for versions, myself was trying to use it and didn't know what has going on.